network turns really slow when opening some app in windows
When I open certain applications, specifically Microsoft Flight Simulator in my case, my network speed drastically decreases to a unusable level. I can't even ping my router. During this process, it looks like that a lot of packets go unprocessed. For instance, as shown in the attached Wireshark analysis, my pc receive the server's SYN+ACK response after retransmitting SYN packet for two times. Interestingly, when I close the application, the network speed returns to normal.
It's not just specific connections that are affected; all connections experience significant slowdowns.
I also checked perfmon.msc and added all the packet drop counters to the monitored metrics, but the graph showed no abnormalities or signs of packet loss.
Any advice or guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated!
